# Is it possible to develop a SharePoint hosted app for SharePoint 2019?

Tags: sharepoint-addin, 2019

We have created a SharePoint 2019 environment.

Is it possible to develop a SharePoint Hosted App for SharePoint 2019?

Because If I create a project for SharePoint Hosted Add in, I cannot see option for SharePoint 2019 target SharePoint version.

[image]

If yes, please share a reference link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of VS are you using?
You need VS 2017 v15.9+ for SP2019 extensions as per [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-2019-development-platform) msdn article.

Comment: I'm using VS 2017 v15. 
Thanks for your response. 
I'll try to upgrade my VS and check.